# Why does cURL use zlib?

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl, zlib

It is possible to compile Libcurl with OpenSSL, SSH2 and zlib support. I found out that OpenSSL is used as an alternative for SSL traffic as it's described on the [FAQ](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html), and I can deduce what SSH2 does, but what exactly is zlib used for?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

HTTP responses can be [compressed with gzip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression). The zlib library is used to decompress these responses.

Comment: FTP data transfers can also be compressed with gzip, though I don't know if libCurl supports that option or not.

Comment: `libcurl` supports 'deflate' (the
zlib algorithm), 'gzip' and 'compress'. See:  http://curl.haxx.se/dev/readme-encoding.html

Comment: @Marc.2377 Certainly, see https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/lib/content_encoding.c for usage of zlib in content encoding related code.